# URL modification when i passed it through the mail

Tags: gmail-api, google-workspace

I am assign the URL to anchor tag href attribute in the template definition to share it though the mail using google gmail API using node js, Once mail received I checked the received try to open the link it as been modified, how to avoid this situation.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "modified"? what is the original URI and changed URI?. Please update your question and add more details.